# Does disabling Getty stop the ability to login via ethernet over SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, raspberry-pi

I'm currently using SSH(via ethernet cable) to login to my Raspberry pi and access it using my Laptop.(using Putty on Windows 8)

I have to use the serial port of Raspberry Pi(in GPIOs tty0) for a certain application. For that the tutorial asks to disable Getty in /etc/inittab by commenting the following line,

```
T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100
```

My problem is; if I disabled "getty" will I be unable to access the Raspberry Pi using SSH? I'm a little worried as Getty is described as the program which displays the remote login screen..